# Drawing sphere in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can i draw two and more spheres with python? For example, I know coords of the center of each sphere and I want to draw them in one graphic.

My code now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


fig = plt.figure(1)    
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 10)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 10)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(x+4, y, z+10, linewidth=0.0)
ax.plot_surface(x+4, y, z, linewidth=0.0)

plt.show()
```

and I have result:
[image: Image of two flattened spheres]

but it doesn't look like spheres

Comment: Seems to me your axes are off, if you set them equal it should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not that the spheres aren't spherical, your problem is that the axes aren't scalled equally. The best workaround seems to be (taken from [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1077/)):

```
ax.auto_scale_xyz((0,10), (-5,5), (0,10))
```

Resulting in:

[image: Image of two spheres]